Bootstrapping SOFR swap curve
I want to know key tenors of SOFR swap for building discounting curve for pricing derivatives.
To build a similar curve to that of Bloomberg ICVS & SWPM, Which instruments should I use?
Which tenors of SOFR swap are key tenors? If you are a practitioner, Please answer to my question.



Ticker
Tenor




USOSFR1Z CBBT Curncy
1W


USOSFR2Z CBBT Curncy
2W


USOSFR3Z CBBT Curncy
3W


USOSFRA CBBT Curncy
1M


USOSFRB CBBT Curncy
2M


USOSFRC CBBT Curncy
3M


USOSFRD CBBT Curncy
4M


USOSFRE CBBT Curncy
5M


USOSFRF CBBT Curncy
6M


USOSFRG CBBT Curncy
7M


USOSFRH CBBT Curncy
8M


USOSFRI CBBT Curncy
9M


USOSFRJ CBBT Curncy
10M


USOSFRK CBBT Curncy
12M


USOSFR1F CBBT Curncy
18M


USOSFR2 CBBT Curncy
2Y


USOSFR3 CBBT Curncy
3Y


USOSFR4 CBBT Curncy
4Y


USOSFR5 CBBT Curncy
5Y


USOSFR7 CBBT Curncy
7Y


USOSFR8 CBBT Curncy
8Y


USOSFR9 CBBT Curncy
9Y


USOSFR10 CBBT Curncy
10Y


USOSFR12 CBBT Curncy
12Y


USOSFR15 CBBT Curncy
15Y


USOSFR20 CBBT Curncy
20Y


USOSFR25 CBBT Curncy
25Y


USOSFR30 CBBT Curncy
30Y


USOSFR40 CBBT Curncy
40Y


USOSFR50 CBBT Curncy
50Y




Should include futures, whites reds greens as they are very liquid (not sure if these go into bbg build)

The colors: https://www.cmegroup.com/education/courses/introduction-to-sofr/understanding-sofr-packs-and-bundles.html I'd say all the way up to 10 years.

To build a similar curve to BBG, you just need to look up the curve on ICVS. It shows all instruments used for curve building.
